# regex to match group of characters

Tags: regex, preg-match

This regex `^.*.*.*.*.*.*00` will return true for this number `10102001` with preg_match.

i know that will catch the first seven numbers, but if the last number is not 0, so, the result should be false and not true. This is what I need. For this number the regex will work as i expect (false):  `10102011`

```
10102001 -- true why?
10102011 -- false
```

What is wrong with the regex?

Comment: The * means 0 or more, so it cancels down to `^.*00`, which again cancels down to `00`

Comment: What do you actually want? Six arbitrary digits followed by two `0`'s and nothing else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.*` will match zero or MORE of any character that is not a line break. Your regex would actually be equivalent to just writing `^.*00`. It matches because there is the substring "1010200" in "10102001".

You will want something like: `^.{6}00` (which is the same as `^......00`) to give you what you want. Better yet, you'd probably want to be more specific and specify that you only want numbers prefixed. So `^[0-9]{6}00`. And if you what to make sure that the 0s at the end are at the very end of the line or target string, then add on a $. `^.{6}00$`

Comment: In addition Frank answer:  `10102011` is false because there no two `0`s in `10102011` string. `^.*` matched but `00` could not.

Answer (score 2):

> 10102001 -- true why?

Because you are not matching to the end of string so the regex will match anything with 00 *somewhere* before the end (anything may follow the zeroes). In addition, `*` means "zero or more", which means that `.*` matches anything - the empty string, ten characters, four characters, 1 character...

Here is a regex that catches everything which starts with 7 characters and ends in two zeroes (9 characters in total):

```
^.......00$
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is all kinds of messed up. The last 5 `.*`s are pointless, `^.*00` would do the same thing.

`10102001` is true because it's matching its substring, `1010200`. It's leaving the 1 on the end off. If you want to check and see if it matches the entire string, use this: `^.*00$`.

Here's what your regex is doing. Add a `$` at the end to see how it should work.

http://www.regex101.com/r/wK3qI1

I can't make any recommendations for how your regex should be other than that, since you haven't posted any constraints.

Answer (score 0):

this should be the right regex for you:

```
[0-9]{7}0$
```